# CMS database schema design advice

Tags: database, database-design, sql, schema

I am designing a CMS, and would like to start with a simple database schema, with the requirements

1. Two main types of entity,`Post` and `Category`
2. For `Post`, it need to support **multilingual** and **versioning**
3. For `Category`, only **multilingual** support is needed.
4. For both type, hierarchical relationship support (see the `parent` field) is needed.

Now, I have prepared a simple design like the following

[image]

I want to seek your expert advices if any improvements can be done or corrections are needed.

Answer (score 5):

A CMS model looks like something complex but lets try to think up something.

- It seems that the relationship between POST and POST_VERSION should be 1:M
- LANGUAGE entity is missing
- POST_VERSION_LANGUAGE should be a join entity between LANGUAGE and POST_VERSION
- COLLABORATOR can have specific ROLES regarding a POST_VERSION, like: authos, translator, proofreader, illustrator, photographer, etc.

Since a PNG is worth 1024 words, here's a conceptual model. I'll be adding edits as you ask questions in the comments section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very nice indeed. JUst two questions: What is `ROLE` and why there is a linkage between `COLLABORATOR` and `LANGUAGE`?

Comment: @Yoga Role is whether a given collaborator is the author of the article, or the translator, or the proofreader, etc. The rows of that table would be: author, translator, proofreader, illustrator, photographer, etc. The relationship between collaborator and language is because the CSM will have multilingual content (as your original design seems to imply by having post_version_language) and each collaborator can have one or more languages in which he is proficient. That would help choose translators or authors for different languae versions of the articles.